# Create List of Dict: python / pandas

Tags: pandas, list, loops, dictionary

I got an import from a Excel which I read with Pandas. In each row is a different person, the columns give values like people_id etc.

Now I actually want to put each person into a dict and later each dict to a list. But unfortunantely my loop returns always the same person, but 19 times in the list. Where is the fault?

```
path = os.path.abspath('dataset_people.xlsx') # works as long as file is in same directory as this code. Excel-file must be closed.
excel = pandas.read_excel(path)# excel is now a variable which contains the files contet. 
#print(excel) #print whole content.

# set dictionary
people = {}

# set list
list_people = []

# loop dictionary
for index, row in excel.iterrows():
    add1 = row['people_id']
    add2 = row['timestamp']
    add3 = row['floor_departure']
    add4 = row['floor_destination']
    people['people_id'] = add1
    people['timestamp'] = add2
    people['floor_departure'] = add3
    people['floor_destination'] = add4

# loop list
for index, row in excel.iterrows():
    list_people.append(people)

print(list_people)
```

Comment: Could not find anything wrong with the code yet. Did you try `excel.to_dict()`

Comment: yes I did, there seems to be a value error: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, you have to append to `list_people` in the first loop, after you have completed the dict entry for a person. Here in the first loop you read the first line, store all the info regarding the person in this row and then you pass to the next row, overwriting the content in the `people` dict for the row you just read. So at the end you have stored in the dict only the info of the last person in the dataframe.

```
for index, row in excel.iterrows():
    add1 = row['people_id']
    add2 = row['timestamp']
    add3 = row['floor_departure']
    add4 = row['floor_destination']
    people['people_id'] = add1
    people['timestamp'] = add2
    people['floor_departure'] = add3
    people['floor_destination'] = add4
    list_people.append(people)
```

A loop like this should do the work you need. In this way each person is in a dict and then this is added to the list. If this is solution is what you are looking for, I sugest you to call the dict `person` rather than `people`, that instead are represented in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunantely it is still not working. I still get this:

[{'people_id': 19, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2020-04-08 06:19:00'), 'floor_departuretamp('2020-04-08 06:19:00'), 'floor_departure': 5, 'floor_destination': 4}, {'peopeparture': 5, 'floor_destination': 4}, {'people_id': 19, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2stamp('2020-04-08 06:19:00'), 'floor_departure': 5, 'floor_destination': 4}, {'peodeparture': 5, 'floor_destination': 4},...]

Comment: You should clarify your question: from this print seems that there is some problem with the data since in the second dict stored in the list there is no `people_id` value and the others specified in the loop. Try to put a print of the first 10 rows of the excel before the loop (`print excel.head(10)`) in your question and then specify better the result you want to obtain in terms of list of dicts.

Comment: Okay i found the fault myself. You need to take the dict down into the loop. Then it works.

Comment: Okay, I will edit my answer indenting it correctly. Sorry for that.